# Handbook of functional analysis for geometry

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

Is there a book or document that could be used as a handbook so I don't have to go through how the space of distributions is constructed and the main theorems in every geometry book?

I do no want to profundise on the topic, but it feels really bad when, for example, a book on compact Riemann Surfaces is about to prove some finite dimensionality and invokes an out of nowhere theorem about compact operators on Hilbert spaces, or when studying the Hodge theorem a very *ad hoc* definition of the spaces of distributions and elliptic operators is presented, because if I find myself trying to prove a similar reult, I will need to know if those tools in functional analysis can be useful.

Also, I find that most of the functional analysis books don't cover the whole topic. Much of them restrict themselves to Banach spaces, for example, skip Hilbert spaces or omit distributions etc. while the ones that cover the whole topic are too long for me.

I know that there are some short texts that gather the *basics* of functional analysis, but I don't want that, I'm looking for a document showing the deep theorems, that skips most of the proofs, but focuses on how to use the results, and I would also like to have a section on distributions and Frechet spaces for the study of holomorphic functions.

This is very specific, but anything close to what I am asking is accepted.

Comment: Maybe your language should be less antagonistic? “An obscure theorem”?

Comment: Sorry @TedShifrin if that was the impression. That theorem does not appear on any classical functional analysis book. Gunnning and Rossi's book dedicates a whole appendix defining functional analysis terms and proving results just to use that result. Sorry but, for me, the idea seems totally disconnected with the topic of the book. I am not saying that the theorem is obscure itself, just that it is very little motivated everywhere it appears, as it happens with distributions and so on. I will change the word obscure, but I think that my question is very clear in general lines

Comment: In general, a functional analysis or elliptic PDE book will not focus on or even state the exact theorems you want, especially on manifolds. You want to find a book with the essentials of linear elliptic theory on a manifold, just enough to do what you need. In general, a book that presents Hodge theory will go through just enough of the linear elliptic PDE theory needed. One book that does this fairly well is F. Warner's Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups.